# Count points in polygon (weighted) for multiple attributes in QGIS 3 in one go

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, point-in-polygon, analysis

Is there a way to count weighted points inside polygons for multiple attributes at one time?

I can count weight points (below) for an individual attribute, which creates a new polygon layer with an updated attribute table. I have ten attributes of the points that I need to aggregate into the polygons, so this would take a long time to do one by one.

I'd considered setting them up as batch processes, but this generates a new layer each time. I'd like to only generate a new layer once.

[image: screenshot of point count dialogue]

Comment: what if you proceed with a Processing Modeler using the `Count points in polygon` function for `n`-times? Where each previous output layer (`n-1`, `n-2` etc.) will be a temporary layer and only the last output (`n`) will be saved a permanent layer when all the necessary attributes were used.

Comment: got this to work?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was rushing through this few weeks ago and ended up using some ID variables in the data to aggregate in Excel. Not pretty but got the job done.

Comment: For anyone encountering the same problem I think Taras's solution is the most direct. But ThingumBob's (below) is preferable if you have experience using SpatiaLite SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mind using *SpatiaLite* SQL?

With both your layers loaded into the project

- open the `<QGIS> | Database | DB Manager...`

  - expand `Virtual Layers | Project Layers` in the left panel
  - open a new `SQL Window` (2nd button from left, top row)
  - paste and run (`Execute`)

    ```
    SELECT py.<id_field>,
           py.<some_other_field_1>,
           ...,
           py.<some_other_field_n>,
           COUNT(pt.<id_field>) AS cnt,
           SUM(pt.<weight_attribute_1>) AS w1,
           ...,
           SUM(pt.<weight_attribute_10>) AS w10,
           py.geometry
    FROM <polygon_layer_name> AS py
    JOIN <point_layer_name> AS pt
      ON ST_Within(pt.geometry, py.geometry)
    GROUP BY py.<id_field>,
             py.<some_other_field_1>,
             ...,
             py.<some_other_field_n>
    ```
  - activate `Add as new layer...`

    - choose new `Layer name` and `Geometry column` (-> *geometry*)
- `<Layer_context> | Save features as...` to export as e.g. *shapefile*

This will select all columns (fields) you specify (`<some other_field_n>`) from the polygon layer (`<polygon_layer_name>`), plus the summed up values (`w1` - `w10`) for each `<weight_attribute_n>` and the count of points (`cnt`) that are within each polygon, into a new polygon layer; of course you can name the new fields as you like (note: for any name having special characters in it, like `"my new #field"`, enclose the name with `""`).

Comment: took me a while to get to trying this out but thanks for the detailed answer!